# If you had one wish for SubSonic what would it be?

Tags: subsonic

I know this question seems subjective but it's really pretty simple. As a long term user, and part time contributor to [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) I'm interested in what the community thinks would be the single best way to improve it.
So what's your opinion, how would you make SubSonic even better? What one thing would make you more likely to use/recommend/evangelise/stop complaining about it?

As I said I know this is a bit subjective and may get closed but as SO is the main support forum for SubSonic I think this could be a useful way to solicit opinion and/or contributions.

To keep this from turning into a general discussion here's the rules:

- No omnibus wishes
- No duplicate wishes
- Up-vote those you agree with rather than re-posting them

Comment: *"as SO is the main support forum for SubSonic"* - I think Subsonic needs to get its own support forum then.

Comment: So you think the same's true of Android then do you? http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/stackoverflow-android-support.php

Comment: This isn't a support question though... In fact, it's a discussion question, a sort of beast that SO is uniquely ill-suited for. Might I suggest the subsonicproject group on Google Groups? If you must attempt to run this here, please lay out some ground rules (no omnibus wishes, no duplicate wishes, up-vote those you agree with rather than re-posting them.) and mark it Community Wiki to encourage voting on wishes.

Comment: A valid point but actually this is a simple question, whichever is the most desired feature gets voted up the most. The google groups doesn't contain anywhere near as many SubSonic users as SO does so this question will get a lot more useful input here.

Comment: @BlueRaja...I dunno, I'm kind of liking how SO is becoming the defacto go-to place for a variety of dev support issues.

Comment: @Shog9 - Good ideas on the community wiki and rules. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ability to run in MediumTrust out of the box

Comment: Just to let you know this is planned for SubSonic 3.1

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty the biggest thing thats lacking is solid documentation and HowTo's

Its got better but I think it needs a lot more.

Comment: So what exactly would you like to see in the docs. What specific how tos would help?

Comment: there should be something to show database farm settups and failover options.

there should be more showings on real world updates, for example i after a while worked out that it was much easier to use reflection to get a string array of columns for inserts, than to write them out
something like this in the docs would be good.

remove the CodingHorror get out clause and list more ways to do things.

update all statements for 3.0.0.3 as most code in docs is invalid

all above is with regards to activerecord its great, brilliant infact but would be good to see more real world

Answer (score 2):

Ability to automatically map collections of other objects, like Fluent NHibernate does.

Answer (score 1):

When SubSonic throws an exception that isn't clear, I'd like to be able to use Google or some other mechanism to discover more information about how to keep my development effort moving forward.  Right now it's too easy to get into a situation where you have to go spelunking into the SubSonic source code since SubSonic doesn't seem to be very proactive when the user goes off the "happy path".

This critique is hardly specific to SubSonic.  Many (most?) software products suffer from this same problem.  I have not really had this problem with NHibernate though, which is SubSonic's most clear competitor.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion.  Though I have to say my experience with Fluent NHibernate is that going off the happy path is equally problematic (plain old NHibernate seems much better documented).  But I've always been able to get the help I need by asking questions on either SO or the FNH mailing list.

Comment: agree im not so bad now but in my first few months you have to self discover because the examples were few and help is rare, but now i play in subsonic core, i know how subsonic wants my tables and fields to look and i use Views to a great extent this makes subsonic really easy and exreme fast to use......  but rob is really missing this stuff of his website

Comment: This is a bit non-specific. I realise that just make it easier to use is desirable but we really need to know what exactly could be done to keep you on the happy path.

Comment: @Adam: Just try to break it, it's not hard.  Standard negative testing.  Put together an invalid config, put together a database using legacy database design concepts, try to use the latest features from the database vendors.  Do things you think SubSonic can't do and then check to see if the error messages are helpful enough and/or documented further on the web.  I'm not at all asking for it to be easier to use.  I'm not asking for better happy path support.  I'm asking for it to break well.

Comment: @Michael: What I'm trying to do here is find specific actions that will help. The thing is I've been using SubSonic for a while so when I break it I generally find it pretty easy to work out what's wrong so for me it feels like it does break well. Obviously this is very much subjective but that's why I'm asking for specifics. Make it break well still seems too vague for me to know what to do about it.

Comment: @Adam: I can't help you then and you can't help me.  Every time I've used SubSonic, I've run into blocking problems without easy answers fairly quickly.  If "it works for you", it works for you.  There are plenty of people who SubSonic doesn't work for and they still need help.

Comment: @Michael: That's why I'm here, trying to help. I can't fix abstracts though so I'm just trying to identify specifics. I do understand your point I'm just trying to keep this question focused.

Answer (score 1):

Faster and higher quality releases

Answer (score 1):

Binary types for SimpleRepository (Images)

Answer (score 1):

Left Outer Joins

Answer (score 1):

Support more database-independent code generation...

What I mean by this is that it is truly a real pain if your application wants to talk to different databases (e.g. SQL Server and Oracle) and you want to only have one set of generated DAL objects. I would love it if you had the option of specifying that any SQL code that gets sent to the DB would be as compatible with most engines as possible, since right now if you generated your objects targeting SQL Server then all queries will be of the form:

SELECT [schema].[table_name] FROM ....

Sadly, this does not work in Oracle, so basically you're out of luck there.

Perhaps this isn't a huge concern for most of you, but I'm currently writing a commercial app that touts one of its main features as being able to run on various database engines just by changing its configuration and I chose SubSonic because I thought it could handle the job pretty easily, but I'm honestly having second thoughts now because of all the hoops I may have to jump through just to get this to work correctly under different environments.

Answer (score 0):

Support MS Access ,Postgres and FireBird database :)....